# Reduction formula for a trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have come upon the following trigonometric integral:
$$\int (\alpha + \sin x)^n \cos^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary real constant and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a nonnegative integer. It resembles some integrals, for which [reduction formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) are known, so my idea has been to find a reduction formula for this case as well. Any ideas how to achieve that? I am not asking for a detailed solution, but some hint how to approach the problem would be helpful.

Comment: By expressing $\cos^2 x$ as $1-\sin^2 x$ and using the binomial expansion for $(\alpha+\sin x)^n$, you have a sum of integrals in the form $\int \alpha^k \sin^j x dx$. By using the De Moivre formula, you have that $\sin^j x$ is a combination of $\sin(jx),\sin((j-2)x)\,\ldots$.