# Asymptotic solution to the integral $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\alpha + \sin x)^n \cos^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

Recently, I have [posted a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532127/15768) on how to find a reduction formula for the trigonometric integral
$$\int (\alpha + \sin x)^n \cos^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
This problem seems to be tough, however. When trying to solve (as proposed in a comment on my previous question) the integral using the Binomial theorem, one obtains a sum that seems to be quite complicated.

Thus, there seems to be only a little chance for a reasonable reduction formula to exist. As a consequence, I became interested in solving the integral asymptotically. So my question is how to obtain a reasonable asymptotic estimate for the following *definite* integral, as $n \to \infty$:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\alpha + \sin x)^n \cos^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x.$$
I have tried to use the [Laplace's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), but with my small knowledge and without any experience, I have not succeeded. Thus, I would be grateful for hints.

Comment: As a starting point you may omit the $\cos$ term and use as suggested the binomial theorem
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} (\alpha + \sin x)^n dx
=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\alpha^{n-k}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^k dx.$$
Obviously the integrals vanish for odd $k$ and for $k=2m$ you have
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{2m} dx = \sqrt{\pi} \frac{\Gamma\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(m+1\right)}$$

Comment: According to my computations the integral is
$$\pi\sum_{k\geq 0} \binom{n}{2k} \left\{\binom{2k}{k}(1/2)^{2k} - \binom{2k+2}{k+1}(1/2)^{2k+2}\right\} \alpha^{n-2k}$$
maybe that will help somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll continue the work started in [David H's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/542688/5531).

It was shown there that

$$
I_\alpha(n) = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\alpha + \sin x)^n \cos^2 x\,dx = \int_{\alpha -1}^{\alpha+1} u^n\sqrt{1-(u-\alpha)^2}\,du.
$$

We consider the cases $\alpha \geq 1$, $0 < \alpha < 1$, $\alpha = 0$, $-1 < \alpha < 0$, and $\alpha \leq -1$.

**Case 1:** $\alpha \geq 1$.  Begin by making the substitution $u = (\alpha+1)e^{-t}$ to get

$$
I_\alpha(n) = (\alpha+1)^{n+1} \int_0^{-\log\left(\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}\right)} e^{-nt} e^{-t} \sqrt{1-\left[(\alpha+1)e^{-t}-\alpha\right]^2}\,dt.
$$

Since

$$
\begin{align}
&e^{-t} \sqrt{1-\left[(\alpha+1)e^{-t}-\alpha\right]^2}\,dt \\
&= \sqrt{2+2\alpha}\, t^{1/2} \left[1-\frac{\alpha+6}{4}t - \frac{3\alpha^2-36\alpha-116}{96}t^2 - \frac{\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+36\alpha+88}{128}t^3 + O(t^4)\right]
\end{align}
$$

as $t \to 0^+$, we can apply [Watson's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_lemma) to obtain the asymptotic expression

$$
\begin{align}
I_\alpha(n) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\alpha+1)^{n+3/2}}{n^{3/2}}\left[1 -\frac{3 (\alpha+6)}{8 n} - \frac{5 \left(3\alpha^2-36\alpha-116\right)}{128 n^2} \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. - \frac{105 \left(\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+36\alpha+88\right)}{1024 n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{4}}\right)\right].
\end{align}
$$

Using more terms in the series expansion of the integrand will yield more terms of the asymptotic expansion of $I_\alpha(n)$.

**Case 2:** $0 < \alpha < 1$.  We split the integral into the two pieces

$$
I_\alpha(n) = \int_{0}^{\alpha+1} u^n\sqrt{1-(u-\alpha)^2}\,du + \int_{\alpha -1}^{0} u^n\sqrt{1-(u-\alpha)^2}\,du = J_1(n) + J_2(n).
$$

In the first we make the substitution $u = (\alpha+1)e^{-t}$ as before, and in the second we make the substitution $u=(\alpha-1)e^{-t}$.  The integrals become

$$
J_1(n) = (\alpha+1)^{n+1} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-nt} e^{-t} \sqrt{1-\left[(\alpha+1)e^{-t}-\alpha\right]^2}\,dt,
$$

$$
J_2(n) = (-1)^n (1-\alpha)^{n+1} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-nt} e^{-t} \sqrt{1-\left[(1-\alpha)e^{-t}+\alpha\right]^2}\,dt.
$$

By applying Watson's lemma to each of these individually we find that

$$
J_1(n) \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\alpha+1)^{n+3/2}}{n^{3/2}}
$$

and

$$
J_2(n) \sim (-1)^n \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(1-\alpha)^{n+3/2}}{n^{3/2}},
$$

so the terms coming from the first integral dominate those coming from the second.  Thus $I_\alpha(n)$ has the same asymptotic expansion as in Case 1.

**Case 3:** $\alpha = 0$.  In this case $J_2(n) = (-1)^n J_1(n)$, so that

$$
I_0(n) = \Bigl(1+(-1)^n\Bigr)\int_0^{\infty} e^{-nt} e^{-t} \sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}\,dt.
$$

Here

$$
e^{-t} \sqrt{1-e^{-2t}} = \sqrt{2}\,t^{1/2} \left[1-\frac{3}{2}t+\frac{29}{24}t^2-\frac{11}{16}t^3 + O(t^4)\right],
$$

so applying Watson's lemma yields

$$
I_0(n) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}} \left[1-\frac{9}{4 n}+\frac{145}{32 n^2}-\frac{1155}{128 n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right].
$$

**Case 4:** $-1 < \alpha < 0$.  This case is similar to Case 2.  The only difference is that the terms from $J_2(n)$ dominate.  We get

$$
\begin{align}
I_\alpha(n) &= (-1)^n \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(1-\alpha)^{n+3/2}}{n^{3/2}} \left[1+\frac{3(\alpha-6)}{8 n} - \frac{5\left(3\alpha^2+36\alpha-116\right)}{128 n^2} \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. + \frac{105 \left(\alpha^3+6\alpha^2+36\alpha-88\right)}{1024 n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right].
\end{align}
$$

**Case 5:** $\alpha < -1$.  This case is similar to Case 1 (and its relation to Case 2).  If we made the substitution $u=(\alpha-1)e^{-t}$ in $I_\alpha(n)$ and applied Watson's lemma we would find that $I_\alpha(n)$ has the same asymptotic expansion as in Case 4.

In summary,

> If $a > 0$ then
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> I_\alpha(n) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\alpha+1)^{n+3/2}}{n^{3/2}}\left[1 -\frac{3 (\alpha+6)}{8 n} - \frac{5 \left(3\alpha^2-36\alpha-116\right)}{128 n^2} \right. \\
> &\qquad\qquad \left. - \frac{105 \left(\alpha^3-6\alpha^2+36\alpha+88\right)}{1024 n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{4}}\right)\right]
> \end{align}
> $$
>   as $n \to \infty$.
>
> If $a = 0$ then
>   $$
> I_0(n) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1+(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}} \left[1-\frac{9}{4 n}+\frac{145}{32 n^2}-\frac{1155}{128 n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right]
> $$
>   as $n \to \infty$.
>
> If $a < 0$ then
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> I_\alpha(n) &= (-1)^n \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(1-\alpha)^{n+3/2}}{n^{3/2}} \left[1+\frac{3(\alpha-6)}{8 n} - \frac{5\left(3\alpha^2+36\alpha-116\right)}{128 n^2} \right. \\
> &\qquad\qquad \left. + \frac{105 \left(\alpha^3+6\alpha^2+36\alpha-88\right)}{1024 n^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right]
> \end{align}
> $$
>   as $n \to \infty$.

Below are some plots of the three regimes for $5 \leq n \leq 40$.  The blue dots are values of $I_\alpha(n)$ obtained numerically and the red dots are the asymptotic approximations obtained above.  The first two terms of the asymptotics are used.

[image]

**Figure 1:** $\alpha = 1/10$.

[image]

**Figure 2:** $\alpha = 0$.

[image]

**Figure 3:** $\alpha = -1/10$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I was up to accept the David H's answer after doing some work on it... But as I see, you have done virtually all of the hard work instead of me. :)

Comment: You're welcome!  I couldn't resist -- the formula obtained by David H was perfect for the method.

Comment: Awesome job,+1. I was pretty sure my formula was gonna be the best place to start, but I'm apparently too rusty to go from there. =p

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the substitution $$u=\alpha +\sin{x},$$ $$du=\cos{x}\space dx,$$ $$\cos{x}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}=\sqrt{1-(u-\alpha)^2}.$$

The third equation is valid on intervals of $x$ where cosine is nonnegative, as is the case for $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$ Then,

$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\alpha + \sin x)^n \cos^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\alpha -1}^{\alpha+1} u^n\sqrt{1-(u-\alpha)^2}du.$$

Applying a simple shift substitution, $v=u-\alpha$, the integral becomes

$$ \int_{\alpha -1}^{\alpha+1} u^n\sqrt{1-(u-\alpha)^2}du = \int_{-1}^{1} (\alpha+v)^n\sqrt{1-v^2}dv .$$

Answer (score 4):

Let me know if any of this needs more details but there is a a fair bit of algebra and it will cloud the discussion if I include it all. By symmetry and trig identities:
$$\int _{-\pi/2 }^{\pi/2 }\! \left( \alpha+\sin \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{n} \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}{dx}=\frac{1}{4}
\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\! \left( \alpha+\sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{
n}\cos \left( 2\,x \right) {dx}+\frac{1}{4}\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\! \left( 
\alpha+\sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{n}{dx} \tag{1}$$
and by two rounds of binomial expansion:
$$\left( \alpha+\sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}
 {\frac {1}{{2}^{
k}}}{n\choose k}{\alpha}^{n-k}{i}^{k}\sum 
_{j=0}^{k}{k\choose j} \left( -1 \right) ^{j}{{\rm e}^{ix(2j-k)}} $$
so $(1)$ is equivalent to:
$$  \sum _{k=0}^{n}  \mathfrak{R}\left( {\frac {{n\choose k}{\alpha}^{n-
k}{i}^{k}\sum _{j=0}^{k} \left( {k\choose j} \left( -1 \right) ^{j}
\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\!{{\rm e}^{ix \left( 2\,j+2-k \right) }}{dx}
 \right) }{{2}^{k+2}}} \right) +\sum _{k=0}^{n} \frac{ 1}{{2}^{k+2}}\left({n\choose k}{\alpha}^{n-k}{i}^{k}\sum _{j=0}^{k} {k
\choose j} \left( -1 \right) ^{j}\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\!{{\rm e}^{ix
 \left( 2\,j-k \right) }}{dx} \right) \tag{2}$$ 
where the real part crops up because I am using only one exponential from the cosine. Then from the integral rep of the [Kronecker delta symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta):
$$\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\!{{\rm e}^{ix
 \left( 2\,j-k \right) }}{dx}=2\pi \delta_{0,2j-k}\quad,\quad \int _{-\pi }^{\pi }\!{{\rm e}^{ix
 \left( 2\,j+2-k \right) }}{dx}=2\pi \delta_{0,2j+2-k}$$
it is evident that we sum only over even $k$ picking out one $j$ term from each inner sum. After a bit of algebra and converting binomial coefficients to factorials we obtain:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int _{-1/2\,\pi }^{1/2\,\pi }\! \left( \alpha+\sin \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{n} \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}{dx}&=\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\sum _{k=0}^{\lfloor  n/2 \rfloor }{
\frac {n!\, \left( 2\,\alpha \right) ^{n-2\,k}}{ \left( k+1 \right) 
 \left( k! \right) ^{2} \left( n-2\,k \right) !}}\\
&=\frac{\pi \,{
\alpha}^{n}}{2}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\,2;\,\frac{1}{\alpha^2})}
 \tag{3} \end{aligned}$$
where $\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}$ is a [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) . Alternatively the result can also be given as a [Jacobi polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials) but the order is integer for odd $n$ only:
$$\frac{\pi \,{
\alpha}^{n}}{2}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(-\frac{n}{2},-\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\,2;\,\frac{1}{\alpha^2})}=\frac{{\alpha}^{n}\pi}{n+1} P_{\frac{1}{2}(n-1)}^{1,-3/2-n}\left(1-\frac{2}{\alpha^2}\right) \tag{4}$$
for which there is a recursion relation etc. In maple you can convert hypergeometric functions to Jacobi polynomials and  vice versa and I expect mathematica does something similar. I appreciate this does not instantly give you the asymptotics but I was thinking you might consider it a  "reduction" (wikipedia cites a "Darboux formula" for the asymptotics of Jacobi polynomials at large order).

You also have the following relation, if:
$$I_{{n}} \left( \alpha \right) =\int _{-1/2\,\pi }^{1/2\,\pi }\!
 \left( \alpha+\sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{n} \left( \cos \left( 
x \right)  \right) ^{2}{dx}$$
then:
$${\frac {d}{d\alpha}}I_{{n}} \left( \alpha \right) =nI_{{n-1}} \left( 
\alpha \right)$$

Comment: The relationship ${\frac {d}{d\alpha}}I_{{n}} \left( \alpha \right) =nI_{{n-1}} \left( 
\alpha \right)$ is an example of what some people refer to as "Feynman's Trick". It's one of those methods that everyone should know yet practically no one does.

Comment: Thank you for your nice and very inspiring answer! I will definitely use some of those tricks later on...

Comment: No worries it was enjoyable, as it happens the Jacobi polynomial can be written with integer order for both even and odd $n$ by applying the final derivative relation to odd order in $(4)$ but I think you got this covered now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look for the maximum value of $f(x)=(\alpha+\sin x)^n\cos^2x$.  For large values of $n$, it will be near $\pm\pi/2$.
Let $x=\pi/2-y$.  $y$ is going to be small, and then use Taylor series.
Take logs of $f(x)$, and differentiate, I get $$\frac{n\cos x}{\alpha+\sin x}-\frac{2\sin x}{\cos x}=0$$
Rearrange, to get $$n\sin^2y=2\cos y(\alpha+\cos y)$$
Expand in Taylor series: the leading term on the LHS is $ny^2$, on the RHS is $2(\alpha+1)$.
So I expect the maximum to be near $y=n^{-1/2}\sqrt{2\alpha+2}$.
Calculate the second derivative of $\log f(x)$ to find the width of the spike.
I get $4\sqrt{\pi}(\alpha+1)^{n+3/2}n^{-3/2}/e$.

Answer (score 1):

I was too lazzy ! Use the binomal expansion and replace Cos[x]^2 by (1 - Sin[x]^2). You then have two almost identical integrals, the general term in the series being Sin[x]^m. The result of its integration between -Pi/2 and Pi/2 is given by

(1+(-1)^m Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[(1+m)/2]) /(m Gamma[m/2])

Is this of any interest ?

Continuing the work, if a is real and positive, then the result of the integral is
(Pi/2) a^n Hypergeometric2F1[(1-n)/2,-n/2,2,1/a^2]

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem for sure. Concerning the integral values, the formulas look nice; they are Pi muliplied by a polynomial of alpha (of degree n). The coefficient of a^n is (1/2). The constant term in the polynomial is zero for odd values of n. In n is even, only even powers of a appear, if n is odd, only odd powers of n appear. I have not been able to establish recurrence relations for the coefficients.

I know this is not the full answer to your question, but may be this could help you finding some tracks. In any manner, thanks for the problem !